# TFS 2018 API (4.1 version) - Python : Can't add an attachment in a result of a run using either 4.1 or 5.1 version

Tags: python, rest, tfs, automated-tests, azure-devops-rest-api

I have managed to send my test results from my automation python script to TFS 2018 by creating a run and adding results to it.

Now, I am trying to upload the xml file I produce with the detailed results of the test execution using the [Create Test Result Attachment API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/create%20test%20result%20attachment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0) . The version of our API is 4.1 and not 5.1 as far as I know.

This is the method I have written in order to achieve what I want:

```
def add_result_attachment(result_id, run_id, filename, stream, conf_object):    

    url = conf_object.config_map('TFS')['url'] + "TFS/_apis/test/Runs/" + str(run_id) + "/Results/" + str(result_id) + "/attachments"

    payload = "{\n    \"attachmentType\": \"GeneralAttachment\",\n    \"fileName\": \"" + filename + "\",\n    \"stream\": \"" + str(stream) + "\",\n    \"comment\": \"Test\"\n}"

    # specify version of tfs and its rest api
    query_string = {"api-version": "5.1-preview"}

    headers = {
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
        'Authorization': MYKEY
    }

    requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers, params=query_string,  verify=False)

    print(str(response.status_code) + "\n" + json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=4) + '\n')
```

I have checked that the URL gives me the correct ids,so it is valid. `filename` contains the absolute path to the xml file i produce using my pytest command.

The `stream` contains the string of the base64 encoded form of this xml file.

When I execute this I get as a response:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marialena\source\repos\UI-Tester\test_signin.py", line 210, in tearDown
    tfs_api.tfs_api.tfs_process(run_start_time, run_completed_time, class_name, method_name, steps, self.outcome)
  File "C:\Users\marialena\source\repos\UI-Tester\tfs_api.py", line 263, in tfs_process
    tfs_api.send_run_results(run_start_time, run_completed_time, json_test_cases['id'], test_name, outcome)
  File "C:\Users\marialena\source\repos\UI-Tester\tfs_api.py", line 586, in send_run_results
    tfs_api.add_result_attachment(result_id, run_id, filename, stream, conf_object)
  File "C:\Users\marialena\source\repos\UI-Tester\tfs_api.py", line 457, in add_result_attachment
    print(str(response.status_code) + "\n" + json.dumps(json.loads(response.text), indent=4) + '\n')
  File "C:\Users\marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\marialena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 2)
```

If I swap `5.1-preview` to `4.1-preview` for version I get status code `400` and the following response:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "innerException": null,
    "message": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: attachmentRequestModel",
    "typeName": "System.ArgumentNullException, mscorlib",
    "typeKey": "ArgumentNullException",
    "errorCode": 0,
    "eventId": 0
}
```

Is there a way to resolve the issue for the `4.1` version in case it is supported by this call or use somehow the `5.1` even if we don't have the latest TFS ? I have tried also to send the attachment to the run itself instead of its result but no luck with that as well.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The version you can use to match an installed TFS is captured [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#api-and-tfs-version-mapping).

Comment: @Matt thank you for repying.. I know that we can use 4.1 as we have update 3 at the moment and from the attachment docs I can see that this api call needs > 5.0 version. So I just wanted to confirm that there is nothing I can do with our current version to send an attachment.

Comment: @Marialena Have you tried to use [Python SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/blob/dev/vsts/vsts/test/v4_1/test_client.py#L86)?

Comment: @TomSun no because I didn't find that sdk when i first wanted to implement a solution for the integration with tfs so i have started implementing everything myself using their REST API calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone is still interested, someone has answered my question [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/446444/tfs-2018-api-41-version-python-cant-add-an-attachm.html).

Basically what needed change was to:

- use a simpler path on the root of the project => `TestsOut.log`
- convert the `stream` in a different way => `stream = str(base64.b64encode(data), 'utf-8')`